# Java: package org.slf4j does not exist

Tags: java, spring-boot, package, frameworks, slf4j

I was trying to build the run. However, I encountered a lot of error(s) on the local workspace. IDE used is intelliJ. Here we go:

[image]

Anyone had experience this kind of error(s)?

Comment: yes, it means (at least) one dependency you need is missing.

Comment: What would be the possible solution you can recommend?

Comment: adding the missing dependencies